# How to sort address alphabetically in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a `dataset` that has bunch of addresses.

```
PROC SORT DATA=work68;
    by ADDRESS ;


run;
```

However it only show `ADDRESS` columns like .. it considers only the very first number of address..

```
2237 Strang Avenue 
2932 Ely Avenue 
3306 Wilson Ave 
3313 Wilson Avenue  
3313 Wilson Avenue 
3313 Wilson Avenue 
46 Nuvern Avenue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option [`SORTSEQ=LINGUISTIC(NUMERIC_COLLATION=ON)`](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Linguistic_Collation) to ask SAS to try and sort numeric values as if they were numbers.

```
PROC SORT DATA=work68 sortseq=linguistic(numeric_collation=on);
    by ADDRESS ;
run;
```

Comment: how about alphabets in the address??

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking?  This won't change how the alphabetic characters are sorted.

Comment: like.. if there are 1107 Ely Avenue and 1111 Huichton Rd. then 1107 Ely Avenue goes first, and then Huichton Rd.

Comment: I AM asking that .. alphabetically .. not the numbers

Comment: is there a way to select just street name and sort by the name?

Comment: So you're saying if you had `1111 Ely Avenue` and `1107 Huichton Rd.` then you would want `1111 Ely Avenue` to go first, i.e. ignoring the house number in the sort?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, you could try creating a new address column with all digits removed and sort on that:

```
data have;
input address $100.;
infile cards truncover;
cards;
1107 Huichton Rd.
1111 Ely Avenue
;
run;

data v_have /view = v_have;
  set have;
  address_nonumbers = strip(compress(address,,'d'));
run;

proc sort data = v_have out = want;
by address_nonumbers;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Proc SQL syntax can sort data in special ways, `ORDER BY <computation-1>, …, <computation-N>`

You may want to sort by street names first, and then by numeric premise identifier (house number).  For example

Data

```
data have; input; address=_infile_;datalines;
2237 Strang Avenue 
2932 Ely Avenue 
3306 Wilson Ave 
3313 Wilson Avenue 
46 Nuvern Avenue
3313 Ely Avenue
4494 Nuvern Avenue
run;
```

Sort on street name, then house number

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select *
  from have
  order by
    compress (address,,'ds')                /* ignore digits and spaces - presume to be street name */
  , input (scan(address,1),? best12.)       /* house number */
  ;
quit;
```

This example has simplified presumptions and will not properly sort address constructs such as `#### ##th Street`